# List difference in java

Tags: java

I have two `ArrayList<Integer>` as follows:

original: `12, 16, 17, 19, 101`

selected: `16, 19, 107, 108, 109`

I want to do difference on these lists such that in the end I have two lists:

Add: `108,109,107`

remove: `12, 17, 101`

Length of original and selected lists varies and one can be greater/smaller than the other

Comment: So basically you want to eliminate values that appear in both lists? Are the lists always sorted as they are in your example?

Comment: Should "Add: `108,109`" be "Add: `107,108,109`"?

Comment: I don't see how either of these is a union OR an intersection.  The intersection would be `16, 19`, e.g.

Comment: @Asaph yes it should be. My mistake

Comment: you are not asking for intersection - change the title

Comment: The title is missleading, you are asking for set difference here, not intersection or union.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
List<Integer> original = Arrays.asList(12,16,17,19,101);
List<Integer> selected = Arrays.asList(16,19,107,108,109);

ArrayList<Integer> add = new ArrayList<Integer>(selected);
add.removeAll(original);
System.out.println("Add: " + add);

ArrayList<Integer> remove = new ArrayList<Integer>(original);
remove.removeAll(selected);
System.out.println("Remove: " + remove);
```

Output:

```
Add: [107, 108, 109]
Remove: [12, 17, 101]
```

Uses Collection's removeAll method. [See javadocs.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection))

Comment: Be aware that `removeAll` removes _all_ occurances of each value - so if '16' was in `selected` twice it still wouldn't be in the final `add`.  So not suitable if you need to detect duplicates (e.g. finding missing, unexpected, and duplicates in a list).

Answer (score 52):

As an alternative, you could use [CollectionUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html) from Apache commons library. It has static **intersection**, **union** and **subtract** methods suitable for your case.

Comment: in my opinion, this should have been the best answer. thanks :)

Comment: Unfortunately it does not support java generics :(

Comment: it does in version 4: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#intersection(java.lang.Iterable, java.lang.Iterable)

Comment: `ListUtils.removeAll` works perfectly,I don't like  jdk's `removeAll` because it modified original Lists and I have to define a new List from Lists to be removed named diff

Answer (score 24):

Intersection: `original.retainAll(selected)`.

After that original will contain only elements present in both collections. Returns true if anything changed.

**WARNING**: This method is very slow for large collections

Comment: True, but it may repeat elements, so it's not strictly an Intersection.

Comment: @kike, if you want not to repeat elements, use a `Set` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)

Answer (score 9):

For intersection and union operations the natural collection type is a Set rather than a List, its also more efficient to use.

Answer (score 6):

Using Guava library:

```
List<Integer> listA = Lists.newArrayList(12,16,17,19,101);
List<Integer> listB = Lists.newArrayList(16,19,107,108,109);
Set<Integer> intersection = Sets.intersection(Sets.newHashSet(listA), Sets.newHashSet(listB));
listA.removeAll(intersection);
listB.removeAll(intersection);
```

Comment: Guavas Sets.intersection is error prone because the second argument is a  `Set<?>`. You can pass e.g. a `Set<String>` and the compiler won't complain.

Answer (score 5):

```
 List<Integer> original;
 List<Integer> selected;

 List<Integer> add = new ArrayList<Integer>(selected);
 add.removeAll(original);

 List<Integer> remove = new ArrayList<Integer>(original);
 remove.removeAll(selected);
```

Be careful with border cases around duplicate elements.  Should cardinality be respected?  As in, if I had `5, 6` originally and `5, 5, 6` after, should add be `5`?  The above works better with `Set`s, since they don't have duplicates (plus `contains()` lookups are faster since they are indexed by the data they contain).

Answer (score 2):

Use this method if you want to get intersection of a list of lists

```
List<Address> resultsIntersectionSet( List<Set<Address>> inputListOfLists )
{
    Set<Address> intersection = new HashSet<>();

    if ( !inputListOfLists.isEmpty() )
        intersection = inputListOfLists.get( 0 );

    for ( Set<Address> filterResultList : inputListOfLists )
    {
        intersection.retainAll( filterResultList );
    }

    return new ArrayList<>( intersection );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a new library available [underscore-java](http://javadev.github.io/underscore-java/). It can do difference and intersection for lists and arrays. [Live example.](http://jdoodle.com/a/vGQ)

Code example:

```
List<Integer> original = Arrays.asList(12, 16, 17, 19, 101);
List<Integer> selected = Arrays.asList(16, 19, 107, 108, 109);
List<Integer> add = U.difference(selected, U.intersection(original, selected));
List<Integer> remove = U.difference(original, selected);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
package LAB8Pack;
import java.util.HashSet; 
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.lang.StringBuilder; 


public class HashSetDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashSet<String> round = new HashSet<String> (); 
        HashSet<String> green = new HashSet<String> (); 


        // Add elements to 'round' and 'green' sets 
        //----------------------------------------------------
        round.add("peas"); 
        green.add("peas");
        round.add("watermelon"); 
        green.add("watermelon");
        round.add("basketball"); 
        green.add("chameleon");
        round.add("chameleon"); 
        green.add("grass");
        round.add("eyes"); 
        green.add("book");

        // Create 'setUnion' and 'setInter'  
        // ---------------------------------------------------
        HashSet<String> setUnion = new HashSet<String>();   

        // Use this to find the intersection
        HashSet<String> SETINTER = new HashSet<String>();   


        HashSet<String> setInter1 = new HashSet<String>(round);
        HashSet<String> setInter2 = new HashSet<String>(green);



        // Add all the elements to one set
        setUnion.addAll(round);
        setUnion.addAll(green);
        SETINTER.addAll(setUnion);



        // Create an intersection
        setInter1.removeAll(green); // Get unique items in round
        setInter2.removeAll(round); // Get unique items in green
        SETINTER.removeAll(setInter2); // Remove items that are unique to green
        SETINTER.removeAll(setInter1); // Remove items that are unique to round
        //----------------------------------------------------


        // DISPLAY RESULTS 
        // ===================================================
        System.out.println("Content of set round"); 
        System.out.println("-----------------------");
        System.out.println(OutputSet(round));

        System.out.println("Content of set green");
        System.out.println("-----------------------");
        System.out.println(OutputSet(green)); 

        System.out.println("Content of set Union");
        System.out.println("-----------------------");
        System.out.println(OutputSet(setUnion));



        System.out.println("Content of set Intersection"); 
        System.out.println("-----------------------");
        System.out.println(OutputSet(SETINTER));
    }




    // METHODS 
    // =======================================================
    static StringBuilder OutputSet (HashSet<String> args) {
        Iterator iterator = args.iterator();
        StringBuilder sB = new StringBuilder (); 

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            sB.append(iterator.next() + " \n");
        }
        return sB; 
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function to find intersection of various collections (more than 2) -

```
public static <T, C extends Collection<T>> C findIntersection(C newCollection,
                                                            Collection<T>... collections) {
  boolean first = true;
  for (Collection<T> collection : collections) {
      if (first) {
          newCollection.addAll(collection);
          first = false;
      } else {
          newCollection.retainAll(collection);
      }
  }
  return newCollection;
}
```

Usage -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  List<Integer> l1 = List.of(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13);
  List<Integer> l2 = List.of(1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13);
  List<Integer> l3 = List.of(2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13);
  Set<Integer> intersection = findIntersection(new HashSet<>(), l1, l2, l3);
  System.out.println(intersection);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8+ streams:

```
List<Integer> result = original.stream()
  .distinct()
  .filter(selected::contains)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```