# Combining ArrayList without duplicates

Tags: java, arraylist

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class SmartCombining {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        Collections.addAll(list1, 4, 3);
        Collections.addAll(list2, 5, 10, 4, 3, 7);

        smartCombine(list1, list2);
        System.out.println(list1);
        System.out.println(list2);
    }

    public static void smartCombine(ArrayList<Integer> first,
            ArrayList<Integer> second) {
        first.addAll(second);
    }    
}
```

So, I want to combine two lists into one, but if the second list contains a number from the first it won't be added. So far my method adds them all together.

Comment: Just call it `extend()`. That is what Python calls it. :-p

Comment: If you don't want duplicate values use a set, e.g. a TreeSet<Integer>

Comment: Don't use a `List`. This is what a `Set` is for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, one way to do it is to iterate through the second list while checking if each element exists in the first list. If it doesn't, add it.

```
public static void smartCombine(ArrayList<Integer> first, ArrayList<Integer> second) {
     for(Integer num : second) {      // iterate through the second list
         if(!first.contains(num)) {   // if first list doesn't contain current element
             first.add(num);          // add it to the first list
         }
     }
}
```

Another way would be for you to hold your values inside a set (like `HashSet`) which doesn't allow any duplicates. Then you can combine them like:

```
first.addAll(second);
```

One more way you could do it is to first remove all elements from the first list that exist in the second list (the ones that would be duplicated). Then you add all elements of the second list to the first list.

```
public static void smartCombine(ArrayList<Integer> first, ArrayList<Integer> second) {
    first.removeAll(second); // remove elements that would be duplicated
    first.addAll(second);    // add elements from second list
}
```

Comment: I don't think OP wants to modify the second list, only the first. Flip that logic around.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl yes, you are right, minor change, just did it

Answer (score 4):

The simple, no brains solution:

```
Set<Integer> joinedSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
joinedSet.addAll(list1);
joinedSet.addAll(list2);
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove duplicates, then merge both lists:

```
list1.remove(list2);
list1.addAll(list2);
```

If you dont want to alter the original list, then first create a backup:

```
list1BP = new ArrayList(list1);
```

Another approach is to use [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), see other answers.

Comment: Looks like people agree with you: [List intersection in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349369/list-intersection-in-java).

Answer (score 2):

Use `Set`, it has been created for that purpose. A `Set` cannot contain 2 identical elements, based on the `equals` method.

```
Set<Integer> list1 = new HashSet<Integer>();
Set<Integer> list2 = new HashSet<Integer>();
```

Using a combination of `ArrayList` and `contains` method is an antipattern here.

Comment: The whole point of using lists is to have ORDERED collections. If you switch to HashSet, you loose that. Maybe your answer would be better with LinkedHashSets or something.

Answer (score 1):

There are two easy way you can combine two Lists and duplicate will be removed.

1) First and very easiest way you can get your output, by creating **equivalent HashSet** object of your ArrayList. Since **HashSet does not allow duplicates.**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    Collections.addAll(list1, 4, 3);
    Collections.addAll(list2, 5, 10, 4, 3, 7);
    System.out.println(smartCombine(list1, list2));
}
public static HashSet<Integer> smartCombine(ArrayList<Integer> first, ArrayList<Integer> second) {
    first.addAll(second);
    HashSet<Integer> hs = new HashSet<Integer>(first);
    return hs;
```

2) There is another way using advanced **for loop**. Iterate the second list  and check if the current element is not in first list and then add the current element.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Collections.addAll(list1, 4, 3);
    Collections.addAll(list2, 5, 10, 4, 3, 7);
    smartCombine(list1, list2);
    System.out.println(list1);
}
public static void smartCombine(ArrayList<Integer> first, ArrayList<Integer> second) {
    for (Integer num : second) {
        if (!first.contains(num)) {
            first.add(num);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note: The second way will work fine only if first list has no duplicates.**

Answer (score 0):

use `contains(Object)` method in `ArrayList`

```
public static void smartCombine(ArrayList<Integer> first,
        ArrayList<Integer> second) {
    for(Integer i :second){
       if(!first.contains(i)) { // if first list doesn't contain this item, add item to the first list.
          first.add(i);
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `ArrayList.addAll()`

Look at this [java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll(java.util.Collection))

As pointer out this would not handle duplicates which can easily be removed using a Set

Comment: Does not handle duplicates.

Comment: i agree it does not. Logic for that will have to be written separately