# How to check the value of an array and compare it to another array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

So here is the case:

We have 5 users. User **A, B, C, D, and E**. And user A have three array like this:

Array I : A, B, C

Array II : A, B

Array III : A

So, Who is the users that are inside all of that array? (The answer should be user A because user A is inside all of that array) but how to check that in java?

> I'm not sure what is the best title of this question

Comment: Please show your current attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: Find the intersection of all arrays

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349369/list-intersection-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add all string arrays to sets, then find the intersection of all sets:

```
String[] array1 = {"A", "B", "C"};
String[] array2 = {"A", "B"};
String[] array3 = {"A"};
Set<String> s1 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(array1));
Set<String> s2 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(array2));
Set<String> s3 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(array3));

// now take the intersection of s1 and s2, followed by s1 and s3
s1.retainAll(s2);
s1.retainAll(s3);

for (String item : s1) {
    System.out.println("common item: " + item);
}
```

This prints:

```
common item: A
```